# Hot to change resized image link on posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have 5000+ posts therefore could you help me to change url link addresses of images on posts as below? I want to change the urls of resized images to their original url.

- **Before:** asd.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sintra.genel_.0.eb_*-XXXxXXX*.jpg
- **After:**  asd.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sintra.genel_.0.eb

- **Before:** asd.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sintra.genel_.0.eb_-300x225.jpg
- **After:**  asd.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sintra.genel_.0.eb

- **Before:** asd.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sintra.genel_.0.eb_-150x150.jpg
- **After:**  asd.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sintra.genel_.0.eb

Comment: what's the reason for doing this? Do you have SSH access to the server? The context is important, e.g. if you've deleted intermediate image sizes and now have broken images, you could use a regenerate thumbnails type plugin to fix that instead of doing this. Also your _after_ examples are missing file extensions, `.eb` isn't an image format

Answer (score 0):

The images are lost after i have used "forced thumbnail image " plugin due to fact that it removed all resized images in the upload folder as i set default image sizes to 0. So i need to use original images on the posts instead of resized ones therefore i need to change every url in posts. I do not want to regenerate images tho. I have access to SSH however i prefer to use phpadmin to make this happen with sql commands if it is possible. thanks